# Forbidden Error while Pulling from private registry during newapp deployment - Openshift origin

Tags: openshift, openshift-origin

I am unable to pull images from my private docker repository while deploying a new-app in openshift origin cluster. I am able to do a pull from my private repository while running a docker pull command and also while running oc cluster up --image

Steps taken to try to resolve the issue:

```
> oc version oc v3.9.0+191fece 
> kubernetes v1.9.1+a0ce1bc657 features:
> 
> openshift v3.9.0+0e3d24c-14 

> kubernetes v1.9.1+a0ce1bc657
```

Whitelisted the docker private repository(registry.test.com) on master-config.yaml

```
imagePolicyConfig:   allowedRegistriesForImport:
  - domainName: docker.io
  - domainName: '*.docker.io'
  - domainName: '*.redhat.com'
  - domainName: gcr.io
  - domainName: quay.io
  - domainName: registry.centos.org
  - domainName: registry.redhat.io
  - domainName: '*.amazonaws.com'
  - domainName: registry.test.com
```

> docker login registry.test.com --> Works
>
> docker pull registry.test.com/namespace/cloudera-hadoop-namenode -->
>    Works
>
> oc cluster up --image registry.test.com/openshift/origin
>   --skip-registry-check=true --> Works
>
> oc create secret docker-registry my-secret
>   --docker-server=registry.test.com --docker-username=user --docker-password=password --docker-email=email

```
> oc describe secrets/my-secret
>     Name:         my-secret
>     Namespace:    myproject
>     Labels:       <none>
>     Annotations:  <none>
>     
>     Type:  kubernetes.io/dockerconfigjson
>     
>     Data
>     ====
>     .dockerconfigjson:  212 bytes
```

> oc new-app registry.test.com/namespace/cloudera-hadoop-namenode
>   --loglevel=10

ERROR

> request.go:874] Response Body:
>   {"kind":"Status","apiVersion":"v1","metadata":{},"status":"Failure","message":"ImageStreamImport.image.openshift.io
>   \"newapp\" is invalid: spec.images[0].from.name: Forbidden: importing
>   images from registry \"registry.test.com\" is forbidden: registry
>   \"registry.test.com\" not allowed by whitelist: \"docker.io:443\",
>   \"*.docker.io:443\", \"*.redhat.com:443\", and 5 more
>   ...","reason":"Invalid","details":{"name":"newapp","group":"image.openshift.io","kind":"ImageStreamImport","causes":[{"reason":"FieldValueForbidden","message":"Forbidden:
>   importing images from registry \"registry.test.com\" is forbidden:
>   registry \"registry.test.com\" not allowed by whitelist: 
>   \"docker.io:443\", \"*.docker.io:443\", \"*.redhat.com:443\", and 5
>   more ...","field":"spec.images[0].from.name"}]},"code":422}
>   dockerimagelookup.go:103] checking local Docker daemon for
>   "registry.test.com//cloudera-hadoop-namenode"
>   dockerimagelookup.go:386] exact match on
>   "registry.test.com//cloudera-hadoop-namenode:latest"
>   dockerimagelookup.go:118] Found local docker image match
>   "registry.test.com//cloudera-hadoop-namenode:latest" with
>   score 0.000000 componentresolvers.go:62] Error from resolver: [can't
>   lookup images: ImageStreamImport.image.openshift.io "newapp" is
>   invalid: spec.images[0].from.name: Forbidden: importing images from
>   registry "registry.test.com" is forbidden: registry
>   "registry.test.com" not allowed by whitelist:  "docker.io:443",
>   "*.docker.io:443", "*.redhat.com:443", and 5 more ...] helpers.go:119]
>   error: can't lookup images: ImageStreamImport.image.openshift.io
>   "newapp" is invalid: spec.images[0].from.name: Forbidden: importing
>   images from registry "registry.test.com" is forbidden: registry
>   "registry.test.com" not allowed by whitelist: "docker.io:443",
>   "*.docker.io:443", "*.redhat.com:443", and 5 more ... error:  local
>   file access failed with: stat
>   registry.test.com//cloudera-hadoop-namenode: no such file
>   or directory error: unable to locate any images in image streams,
>   templates loaded in accessible projects, template files, local docker
>   images with name
>   "registry.test.com//cloudera-hadoop-namenode"

Comment: Are you using the ``--use-existing-config`` option and did you run ``oc cluster down`` and then ``oc cluster up`` after modifying the ``master-config.yaml`` file? The file is not automatically reread on changes.

Comment: Thanks Graham, that was the step i was missing. its able to now pull images from my private registry